# Intellij doesn't show port of running services

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, microservices

I've downloaded the latest Intellij 2023.1.4.

When I run multiple microservices it doesn't show the port where it's running.
I would like to have it including ports.
I was going through the settings of Intellij but didn't find where to enable it / why it is hidden.

Intellij 2023.1.4

[image]

Older version

[image]

Comment: It looks like a known issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-246913/Services-Spring-Boot-Port-Number-not-always-shown